# How get the data you want after requesting permission approval ( Android app )?

Tags: java, android

How can I get the data I want after the user approves the requesting permission? I know how to make the request permission, but after that, how can I take the data out of it?

Comment: i think if you are requesting the user's permission then you must also declare this in your manifest file also like if you wanna read data from the user's device add this permission to your manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and so on

Comment: Allright, but let's say that I make an app that counts how many messages I sent to each person, than I want to count how many messages I sent to each person in the message app. How can you get that ? Because I don't now after al these declarations and approvals, how can I really get the info I want.. I know it's wrong but do you really write something in your could like "int messages = MessageApp.CountMessages(String personName )